# scoping issues between a global variable and enum

Tags: c++, class, scope

```
#include <iostream>

const int SIZE = 5;

struct tester
{
    int array[SIZE];

    enum 
    {
        SIZE = 3
    };

    void size()
    {
        std::cout << sizeof(array) / sizeof(int);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    tester t;
    t.size();
    return 0;
}
```

As we know that

Names defined at any point in a class are in scope in all member functions of the class. Thus the `enum` SIZE is in scope in the function size and hides the global variable SIZE.
so my array size should print 3 instead of 5, but when I compile it is showing it is undefined. Why what is happening here?

Comment: You mention "function foo" but there is none such in your code.  Clarify?

Comment: how do you want the array to be 3 if the enum comes after the declaration? ORDER MATTERS

Comment: Compilers, generally, do things in the order the text appears in the source file. If you move the enum up above the array declaration, you will get a different result.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "when I compile it is showing it is undefined."?

Answer (score 1):

For me it prints 5, unless you put the enum before array definition. Then it's 3.

Just like it's expected (VS2012).

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: i am using dev c++ my error is [Error] changes meaning of 'SIZE' from 'const int SIZE' [-fpermissive]

Comment: Well, the error comes from the change of SIZE *after* it had been used. If you put the enum before the array, the error vanishs. This is an error for gcc (which DevC++ uses) to prevent such ambiguities.

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting the SIZE after you have set the array. If you want the array to be 3, you should put the enum before the array.

Answer (score 0):

You're redefining SIZE, and hence your compiler gives you the "changes meaning of" error that you mention in one of your comments.